# Hardness of perimeter minimization?

Tags: computer-science

Given $xy=C$ where $x, y$ are integer variables  and $C$ is integer constant.

> What is the most efficient algorithm that finds $x,y$ such that $x+y$ is minimum?

Providing references is highly appreciated.

Edit: Input integers are reasonably encoded.

Comment: Isn't this just a constrained optimization problem, restricted to integer solutions?  Of course, one first needs to figure out what integers x and y multiply to C, which is the same as factoring C...

Comment: @Aaron, yes, factorization is a special case. I'm interested in references to geometric approaches.

Comment: This is just the question of finding the factors of $C$ nearest the square root of $C$. In general factorizing an is hard. One special case where a "geometric" approach might be useful is when $C$ factors into a lot of small primes which you know. Then the problem reduces to finding integer values of $a_i$ in certain ranges making $\sum_i a_i\log p_i$ as close as possible to $(1/2)\log C$. This is finding which of a bunch of points is closest to a hyperplane. Americo, that's the maximum! Look at say $C=100$. Then $1+100 > 10+10$.

Comment: Robin Chapman: That's right! My big mistake.

Comment: ... as you wrote above "That is just the question of finding the factors of $C$ nearest the square root of $C$."

Comment: @Robin, Could you please convert you comments into an answer?